# Is there a way to make assertions only on selected array elements?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, supertest

Let's say I want to check if an array contains an element with a certain value of a field that fulfills a given assertion, for eg.:

```
{ array: [ { element1: Mario, element2: White }, { element1: Luigi, element2: Green } ] }
```

Here I want to check that the element of array which has element1 equal to Mario has element2 equal to White. How can I do so with chai/supertest (or other npm packages)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jsonpath module:

```
var jp = require('jsonpath');
expect(jp.query(json, '$..array[?(@.element1=="Mario")]')[0].element2).to.equal('White')
```